# Is phase shifting all the harmonics in $f(t)$ by π the same as multiplying $f(t)$ by -1?

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-transform

Given 
$sin(\omega t + π) = −sin(\omega t)$

and

$cos(\omega t + π) = −cos(\omega t)$

see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

***Is phase shifting each of the harmonics in a function, f(t), by π the same as multiplying f(t) by -1?***

Assume $f(t)$ can be decomposed into harmonics with no constant term.

I think the answer must be yes, but I can not find a reference, identity or proof--would appreciate one of these.

Comment: You seem to be making some restrictive assumptions about $f(t)$--at least that it can be decomposed into harmonics with no constant term. If $f(t) = sin^2 t,$ for example, your idea doesn't work. If you want someone to offer a proof, I suggest editing the question to be more specific about what kind of function $f(t)$ you have in mind.

Comment: @David K; thanks--did that.